# Get row index during loop through all DataGrid ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to get row index or item index of a particular DataGrid item. I've get all items from loop through itemsource as,

```
foreach (Item item in Datagrid.ItemsSource)
                {
                    if (item.Code != null)
                    {
                        if (code == item.Code)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("equal");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

in above code, i've applied some condition if `code==item.code` then message appears. At this condition, i also want to get that item index or row index also. How to get that.

Note: i've an idea to do that on Datagrid itemsource load, also bind index of Datagrid with Item object and get whenever required. but it seems complex logic. Is there any simplest solution?

Datagrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Load Datagrid items by this,

```
void AddValues()
    {
        Datagrid.ItemsSource = null;
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        list.Clear();

        for(int i = 0; i<30; i++)
        {
            string number = i.ToString();
            Item item = new Item()
            {
                Code = "1",
            };
            list.Add(item);
        }
        Datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask LINQ to count the rows that don't match, which is equivalent to the zero-based index of the first matching item.

```
var index = Datagrid.ItemsSource.Cast<Item>()
    .TakeWhile
    ( 
        item => item.Code != code 
    )
    .Count();
```

For code clarity you might want to put this in an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,bool> func)
    {
        return source.TakeWhile( item => !func(item) ).Count();
    }
{

var index = DataGrid.ItemsSource.Cast<Item>().IndexOf( i => i.Code == code );
```

Comment: I expect this method return wrong indices if DataGrid was sorted by some column by clicking on column's header